# IM client with one window(contact list + message window) interface?

Tags: instant-messaging, user-interface, jabber, mirc, icq

What me need ? mirc style interface with merged contact list window and message window 
jabber, icq protocols..
In miranda this not possible with currently available plugins.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind a little work, [bitlebee](http://www.bitlbee.org/main.php/news.r.html) + your favorite irc client would do

Comment: Use this right now, but native client would be better

Comment: what os? if its linux, one of the command line based ones like centerim or finch might be worth looking at

Comment: Yes, but it's Windows

Comment: technical, it should be possible with Pidgin: http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/5782

Answer (score 0):

Try '[weechat](http://www.weechat.org/)':

> WeeChat is a fast, light and extensible chat client. It runs on many
>   platforms (including Linux, BSD and Mac OS).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think Tkabber might suit you. It is not a best looking one, but featureful with layout you like.

You need to setup ICQ transport on your jabber account though, to get ICQ connectivity.

You may checkout the [screenshots](http://tkabber.jabber.ru/node/334) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Meebo: http://www.meebo.com/. Web browser-based, so you can have it in it's own browser window, you don't have to install anything, it's cross-platform, and it's based on libpurple so it has great protocol support.